# How to only check for only the URL by using toHaveBeenCalledWith?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am testing an API and want to check if the correct api URL has been used. Now it seems that I can use [toHaveBeenCalledWith](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) for that. However, it returns everything that was in the options of that request:

```
Expected: "http://localhost:5000/myUrls"
Received: "http://localhost:5000/myUrl", {"headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer foobar", "Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Request-ID": "15863752509339714997334447706"}}
```

What is the common practice to only check for the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the second argument to be anything:

```
expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    "http://localhost:5000/myUrls",
    expect.anything()
);
```

See here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanything

Comment: didn't work for me -> property 'anything' does not exist on type ... { etc }